# NEXT.js adding footer component to layout page destroyed my entire layout, how can i fix it?

Tags: next.js

```
    <div>{children}</div>
    <Footer/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Footer component destroyed the entire layout of my page

Everything was working fine, when i added the footer component and built the project my entire layout was all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by throwing the  component in a html footer tag.

```
  <div>{children}</div>
  <footer>
     <Footer/>
  </footer>
```